# PageRequestManager is undefined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am seeing this error intermittently.  My app throws PageRequestManager is undefined and so fails to load.  Oddly enough this only happens in firefox, ie loads fine.  Anyone know what this error means.  I've been working on the app for some time and I just started seeing this today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means that there is a javascript error somewhere on the page that hits FF but not IE.  Do you have FireBug installed in FF and can you see if there a javascript error that is causing the javascript to fail to be completely parsed?